# SqlAlchemy .filter() values based on not Null value

Tags: sqlalchemy

Let me give you an example:

```
some_input_1 = 2
some_input_2 = None
some_input_3 = 'Foo'


result = session.query(Mytable).filter(Mytable.value1 == some_input_1,
                                       Mytable.value2 == some_input_2,
                                       Mytable.value3 == some_input_3).all()
```

How could I make query ignore `some_input_2` given it has a value of `None` in this case? I would like to have fixed code with query, but have `Mytable.value...` always ignoring the inputs which would be None. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest to just filter it out before you build the query using regular Python since this doesn't seem to involve the database at all.  There are also `and_`, `or_`, `not_`, etc. from `sqlalchemy.sql`.

```py
and_args = [col == val for (col, val) in [
    (Mytable.value1, some_input_1),
    (Mytable.value2, some_input_2),
    (Mytable.value3, some_input_3),
] if val is not None]


result = session.query(Mytable).filter(*and_args).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the list of conditions. And add to this list only those of them, whose values are not `None`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, sessionmaker

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Mytable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    value1: Mapped[int]
    value2: Mapped[int]
    value3: Mapped[str]


some_input_1 = 2
some_input_2 = None
some_input_3 = 'Foo'

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# And you can use your models
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with session_maker() as session:
    conditions = []
    if some_input_1 is not None:
        conditions.append(Mytable.value1 == some_input_1)
    if some_input_2 is not None:
        conditions.append(Mytable.value2 == some_input_2)
    if some_input_3 is not None:
        conditions.append(Mytable.value3 == some_input_3)

    result = session.query(Mytable).filter(*conditions).all()
```

Output:

```
SELECT mytable.id AS mytable_id, mytable.value1 AS mytable_value1, mytable.value2 AS mytable_value2, mytable.value3 AS mytable_value3 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytable.value1 = ? AND mytable.value3 = ?

(2, 'Foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77771032/5320906), [2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77771029/5320906) recommend, the **right way to do this** is to filter the `None` criteria before building the query.

If you really want to keep the fixed query structure, you could try to remove the `None` criteria after the query is defined, but before the query is executed, by adding a listener for a [do_orm_execute event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.SessionEvents.do_orm_execute) and mutating the filter inside the listener.  For example. this code would work:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
...
# Define a session factory, for example
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine)

@sa.event.listens_for(Session, 'do_orm_execute')
def receive_do_orm_execute(orm_execute_state):
    if orm_execute_state.is_select:
        where_criteria = orm_execute_state.statement._where_criteria
        filtered_where_criteria = [
            wc
            for wc in where_criteria
            if not (
                wc.operator is sa.sql.operators.is_
                and isinstance(wc.right, sa.sql.elements.Null)
            )
        ]
        orm_execute_state.statement._where_criteria = tuple(filtered_where_criteria)
```

This code inspects the query's `where` criteria and removes those which form an `IS NULL` condition. While it works in the latest release of SQLAlchemy (2.0.23), it depends on a private attribute (`_where_criteria`), so there is *no guarantee that it will work in future versions*.